# RX PropertyChanged GroupBy deadlock

Tags: system.reactive, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to use Reactive Extensions to throttle PropertyChanged notifications. There are examples of doing this using GroupBy, but with one Subscription created for each PropertyName.

I want to handle the PropertyChanged event for all properties, and I need to Throttle those events for each PropertyName.

This is what I have so far, but it causes a deadlock.

```cs
ValuesPropertyChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(value, "PropertyChanged")
    .GroupBy(o => o.EventArgs.PropertyName)
    .First()
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Subscribe(args => HandlePropertyChanged(args.EventArgs.PropertyName));
```

The deadlock happens in the call to .First().

It still locks if I change that line to:

```cs
.Select(o => o.First())
```

I have also tried

```cs
.Select(o => o.FirstAsync())
```

The examples for GroupBy [here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#GroupBy) look pretty concise, but I am incapable of wrapping my head around converting these examples to my solution.

Why does this cause a deadlock, and what should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this might be what you're after:

```cs
// assume MyObj : INotifyPropertyChanged, naturally
var value = new MyObj();

Action<string> HandlePropertyChanged = 
    name => Console.WriteLine("Got a change for name:" + name);

// The query
var valuesPropertyChanged = 
    // create from event stream
    from propChange in Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
             value, 
             "PropertyChanged")            
    // group events by property name
    group propChange by propChange.EventArgs.PropertyName into batchByName
    // Throttle the resulting batch
    from throttledByName in batchByName.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    // then select each item of the "throttled output"
    select throttledByName;

valuesPropertyChanged.Subscribe(args => 
    HandlePropertyChanged(args.EventArgs.PropertyName));

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
{ 
    value.Value1 = i.ToString(); 
    value.Value2 = (i-1).ToString();
}
```

Output:

```cs
Got a change for name:Value2
Got a change for name:Value1
```

---

Here is the same but with extension methods:

```cs
var valuesPropertyChanged =
    Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                _vm,
                "PropertyChanged")
                .GroupBy(propchange => propchange.EventArgs.PropertyName)
                .Select(o => o.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                .Merge();
```

Comment: Excellent, this does do what I want, and I have managed to get the same working with Extension methods using this as an example. Thank you

Comment: @TriggerPin Cool, no problem! I always find the "verbose" syntax very handy when first setting up Rx queries...I can always optimize/chain them later on.